# Codeigniter update select options based on other select option

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

So, I am fairly new to codeignitor and was hoping to get some help. Below I have my controller(Estimates.php), my model(Invoice_items_model.php) and my view(_add_edit_items.php). These are shortened versions as the full versions are pretty long.

What I am looking to do is have it so that when one of the select options is clicked it will then check the $suboption['non_compatible'] field for that suboption. If the suboption in any of the other select options matches that non_compatible field it will be disabled.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277361/how-to-change-a-select-list-option-when-other-select-list-changed) that I could probably work with but i'm not sure how to do an onchange event for dynamically generated selects.

**Estimates.php**

```
 `public function estimate($id = ''){$data['platforms']         = $this->invoice_items_model->get_platforms();
$data['options']           = $this->invoice_items_model->get_options();
$data['suboptions']        = $this->invoice_items_model->get_suboptions();
$this->load->view('admin/estimates/_add_edit_items', $data);}`
```

**Invoice_items_model.php**

```
public function get_platforms()
{
    $platforms = array();
    $this->db->order_by('name', 'asc');    

    return $this->db->get('tblplatforms')->result_array();
}
public function get_options()
{
    $options = array();

    return $this->db->get('tblplatform_options')->result_array();
}
public function get_suboptions()
{
    $suboptions = array();

    return $this->db->get('tblplatform_suboptions')->result_array();
}
```

}'

**_add_edit_items.php**

```
          <?php foreach($options as $option) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td><p><?php echo $option['name']; ;?>:</p></td>
              <td>
                <select name="<?php echo $option['name']; ?>" id="<?php echo $option['name']; ?>" rows="4" class="form-control">                     
                  <?php foreach($suboptions as $suboption) { ?>
                    <?php if($suboption['plat_option'] ==  $option['name']) { ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $suboption['name']; ?>" id="<?php echo $suboption['name']; ?>"><?php echo $suboption['name']; ?></option>
                    <?php } ?>
                  <?php } ?>
                </select>
              </td> 
            </tr>
          <?php } ?>
          <tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

keep your code as it is just change the event like this.

```
$(document).on("onChange", "your_selector", function() {
   // your code
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is the "your_selector" i'm not sure what it is since it is dynamically pulled from an editable database.

Comment: your_selector mean for ex. if you code $("#mySelectBox").click(), Thn "#mySelectBox" is selector.